# Unwrapping Zod object

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

if I have an Zod object like this:

```
const c = z.object({a: z.object({b: z.string()})});
```

Is it possible to unwrap "c" so that i get an object that looks like this?

```
{a: z.object({b: z.string()})}
```

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was very simple. Just use the "shape" property on the zod object:

Like this:

```
const unWrappedC = c.shape; // returns {a: z.object({b: z.string()})}
```